# wordpress disable login redirect from homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have inherited a wordpress site. It's on a server and all ready to go. When I visit the url it has a redirect set up to the login page. The url looks like this:

http://www.domain.de/wp-login.php?redirect_to=%2F

I've looked in the wp-config.php with the hope of redefining the url there but no joy.

What file should I edit to remove this redirect?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you paste your .htaccess file? You Pastebin or similar service to paste it.

Comment: the query string indicates PHP is doing the redirect rather than apache (htaccess)... that said, i wasn't redirected at all when i tried it.

Comment: It's either a plugin or in the theme.  I've done this before on a site that was for internal company use, but some developers do it on dev sites. Have a look and see if there's a plugin called 'members' (by Justin Tadlock), it's an easy way of doing this quickly.  If it's there then disable it.  If not then look in functions.php for a custom method using `is_admin()`